# Why is $\arg z$ continuous on the arc of the unit circle of those points with $|\arg z |< \frac{1}{2}\pi$

Tags: analysis, continuity

I am looking for an intuitive/ simple argument why $\arg z$ is continuous on the arc of the unit circle of those points with $|\arg z| < \frac{1}{2}\pi$.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand the problem, $\theta \longmapsto \mathrm e^{\mathrm i \theta}$ is a diffeomorphism for $-\frac{1}{2}\pi < \theta < \frac{1}{2}\pi$.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand what a diffeomorphism is. Is there perhaps a less technical argument? Thank you for your reply!

Comment: @FlybyNight Is it the case that $f(z)$ continuous implies $arg(f(z))$ continuous? In this case I suppose $f$ is just the identity map...?

Comment: A diffeomorphism is a differentiable homeomorphism. So it's a one-to-one map which is infinitely differentiable, and whose inverse is infinitely differentiable. It's a much stronger condition than a homeomorphism, which is a continuous map with a continuous inverse.

Answer (score 0):

A function $f$ is continuous at a point $p$ if:

For every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is some $\delta >  0$, such that for all $x$ with $|x-p|< \delta$ we have $|f(x)-f(p)|<\varepsilon$

Consider $\left|\mathrm e^{\mathrm i x}-\mathrm e^{\mathrm i p}\right|=\left|\cos x + \mathrm i \sin x - \cos p - \mathrm i \sin p\right|=\left|(\cos x-\cos p)+\mathrm i(\sin x - \sin p)\right|$. Applying the definition of the modulus, we get 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left|\mathrm e^{\mathrm i x}-\mathrm e^{\mathrm i p}\right|^2 &=& (\cos x-\cos p)^2 + (\sin x - \sin p)^2 \\ \\
&=& 2-2\cos x\cos p - 2 \sin x \sin p \\ \\
&=& 2(1-\cos(x-p))
\end{eqnarray*}
If $\left|\mathrm e^{\mathrm i x}-\mathrm e^{\mathrm i p}\right| < \varepsilon$, then $2(1-\cos(x-p)) < \varepsilon^2$, and so $\cos(x-p) > 1-\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^2$. Hence, choose
$$0 < \delta < \arccos\left(\frac{2-\varepsilon^2}{2}\right)$$